# After sdie by side div, I want a new line on left side Css position

Tags: css

I have css question about position. After sdie by side  div, I want a new line on left side .The output like the below. Would someone tell me how to achieve it. Thanks in advance.

the ideal output on the page:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------_------------
| left                                                                        Right |
| New line New line New line New line New line New line                             |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Current output:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| left                                                                         Right|
|                              New line New line New line New line New line New line|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

There is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
h2.pos_left {
position: relative;
left: -20px;
}

h2.pos_right {
    position: relative;
    left: 20px;
}
.Right{
float: right;
text-align:right;

}

.Left{
float: left;
}

.clear{
   clear: both;
} 

.newline{
     float: left;
      text-align:left;    

}

</style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="Left">left</div>
  <div class="Right">Right</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="newline">New line New line New line New line New line New line </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS is right.  Your HTML is not.  You never close your Right div so the browser thinks your newline div is inside that div.  Change

```
<div class="Right">Right<div>
```

to

```
<div class="Right">Right</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With pure css remove from `.Right` class `float:right`:

```
.Right{
    /*float: right; Remove this */
    text-align:right;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t3qJx/1/)